# Massively deleting SQL rows "skipping" valid foreign key references

Tags: mysql, sql

Due to some error that happened in the past, I have a `files` table (that contains references to where the files are stored on the file system) that has many entries for the same actual file.
So for example

```
 id |      path      |   name
----+----------------+-----------
  1 | '/tmp/images/' | 'foo.jpg'
  2 | '/tmp/images/' | 'foo.jpg'
  3 | '/tmp/images/' | 'foo.jpg'
  4 | '/tmp/images/' | 'bar.jpg'
  5 | '/tmp/images/' | 'bar.jpg'
  6 | '/tmp/images/' | 'baz.jpg'
```

and so on. Those duplicates are, in reality, in the order of 2000 rows for each actual file, so my table is actually much bigger than what it should be, for no actual good reason.

The `id` column is used as a reference for foreign keys in my database, in various tables. For example, my `products` table has `thumb_id` and `cover_id` that both reference the `id` field of the `files` table, then the `users` table has a `profile_pic_id` that also points to the `id` field of the `files` table, and so on.

Now, knowing that (due to a bug in the way those files were imported into my system), all the duplicates are related to one specific filesystem path, I would like to do something like

```
DELETE FROM files WHERE path = '/tmp/folder-with-duplicates'
```

while somehow instructing MySQL to not touch the rows that are actually "in use" (as in, referenced as a foreign key in some other table).

I know that I can add `not in` conditions to my query to check that (I already looked at questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002307/sql-remove-rows-whose-associations-are-broken-orphaned-data)), but this table is referenced by many other tables and figuring out all the associations and writing every single `not in` condition would be extremely tedious.
Of course I cannot disable the constraint because my goal is to keep (*only*) those lines that are being referenced, so I was wondering if there was some way to instruct MySQL to delete "gracefully", or, to put it another way, to ignore the rows that would trigger the foreign key constraint in the `delete` query.

Comment: Try using `DELETE IGNORE ...`

Comment: Make sure you don't have the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option in the foreign keys.

Comment: The CASCADE clause would only tigger when rows in the tables where the foreign keys are being deleted though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Like @Barmar said, if your FK is set up right it will just refuse to delete the rows that are referenced in FKs - if you update your FK to `ON DELETE RESTRICT` and run the delete it should delete everything that isn't referenced as an FK.

Comment: No, it's the other way: The rows with foreign keys are deleted when the row they reference is deleted.

Comment: @mrodo Cascade deletes the rows in the child tables when you delete the parent records, FK is child references parent, and for you the parent is the files table id based on what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure none of the foreign keys have the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. Then use the `IGNORE` option to `DELETE` to skip deleting rows that would cause errors due to the missing foreign key.

```
DELETE IGNORE FROM files WHERE path = '/tmp/folder-with-duplicates';
```

Comment: Thanks, `DELETE IGNORE` was exactly whet I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your foreign key set up properly, it won't allow you to delete the rows referenced by other tables. By default mySQL uses the "Restrict/No Action" on delete rule if it's not specified on the FK, which prevents deleting any rows that are referenced in an FK relationship, so your FK would prevent deleting any row in `files` where there's a matching reference from thumb_id if set up like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (thumb_id) REFERENCES files(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

If you have it set up differently (you shouldn't for this kind of use) with `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL` then you need to drop the existing FK relationship and create a new one using `ON DELETE RESTRICT` to replace it. Once you do do your delete as normal, with `IGNORE` so it just skips the rows that error out - because of the FK rules.