# Fastest way to get number of records in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a faster method to get the record number of a huge mysql table (~3 mil rows) ?

I don't want to list them, only to get the total.

Thanks

Comment: Same question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM table;
```

Comment: oh, it looks i need to count the same field in the where argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl;
```

If "id" is an index this should be pretty fast.

If you use a WHERE too, the index has to be a covering index (contain all rows in one index)

See http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html

Comment: The ID is the primary index and is still very slow. 1 row in set (3.45 sec)

Answer (score 0):

You could just say:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE;`

That should display the number of records in the table.