# Count the records of a query

Tags: mysql, sql

All I need to do is to count all records that match this query... that is the only info I need.. is the count of the records... what is the most efficient way to do that?

```
SELECT id, country, city
FROM sales
WHERE country='Germany'
AND city='Munich'
AND closed<>0
```

I mean, I assume this is correct but is there a more efficient way to do this? I will be running this counting query often...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM sales
WHERE country='Germany'
AND city='Munich'
AND closed<>0
```

Should I use `*` or something more specific?

Comment: It is as fast as you can get. Just make sure that you have all necessary indices on columns that you use in `WHERE` clause. ANd as usual with performance concerns `EXPLAIN` is your friend.

Comment: If you use * it count all the rows, but if you specific a column, it doesn't count rows that is null in specified column.
do you need accurate count , estimated count is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to count the Null value also for your record count then use count(*) or if ignore the Null value to be counted then use count().

```
DECLARE @AA AS TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @AA VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO @AA VALUES(2,'A')
INSERT INTO @AA VALUES(3,'B')
INSERT INTO @AA VALUES(4,'C')

SELECT * FROM @AA

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @AA

SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM @AA
```

As you execute the above query you can find that there will be four records in @AA table but if you use COUNT(*) if will result 4 and if you use COUNT(NAME) it will result 3 this example is for SQL Server, but the mysql will do same.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following link.

[MySQL: Fastest way to count number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows)

Hope this helps you.