# Getting the count of results returned by a MySQL Query with JDBC in the most performance efficient way

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc

The accepted way of getting the number of results from a JDBC result seems to be, to do `resultSet.last()`, and then `resultSet.getRow()`, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192104/49153). But, in that answer, the author also says:

> it may not be a good idea as it can mean reading the entire table
>   over the network and throwing away the data. Do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   ... query instead.

I'm looking for a definite answer on this. Performance wise, will it be better to do a separate `COUNT(*)` query to get the number of results, or will it be better to do `resultSet.last()` and `resultSet.getRow()`, followed by `resultSet.first()` again?

If the ResultSet has already fetched the results and is holding them in memory, then it'd undoubtedly be better just to do `last()` and `getRow()` as (I assume) it would just loop over the results in the memory. But the OP's answer above seems to imply that it lazy loads the results from the db as they're requested.

Comment: Just my thought. If your end goal is to count the number of results why would you parse each row of the table to get a count. Is this extra work really required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Fastest way to count number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows)

Comment: The point that the author of that answer was making is that, in some JDBC drivers, `ResultSet#last()` will point you to the end and you are **unable** to use `ResultSet#first()` because the pointer will take you to the end of `ResultSet`, thereby exhausting it. I've seen this happen. In some JDBC situations, `ResultSet#next()` is really the only way to iterate through. In these situations, `ResultSet#first()` really doesn't even work.

Answer (score 1):

Making a separate query is not a good solution (on my opinion) because server will search rows twice for one result set.

To prevent "double" query MySQL has function FOUND_ROWS(), it returns a number of rows founded for current conditions from `WHERE` clause. This is very useful when you use LIMIT and OFFSET in the query.
I believe that using this function is a better solution.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

I had read some time ago that JDBC streams rows from server, but this was not official documentation and I can't tell how it works in the present, but queries can be different - with difficult sub-queries and joins. I think that server can finish all resources if will "stream" these rows only when client asked for them.

Comment: `found_rows()` doesn't seem to be any good for any queries which don't use limit.

Answer (score 1):

According to me it depends on your use case. If you `resultset` is small enough then the performance difference would be negligible. I highly doubt that the `resultset` fetches the whole result in the main memory for larger resultsets. To second this here is the [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/307287/JDBC/databases/ResultSet-works-PreparedStatment-handicaps) that talks about this particular scenario. In such case calculating size using `last()` , `getrows()` followed by `first()` would be obviously inefficient as it has to first load the portion of `resultset` in memory and perform these operations(and don't forget the network transfer time) to calculate the net size. On the other hand `count(*)` would just go in and count the rows in your result set.

*This is my understanding of which one out performs other. I am open to any inputs from others*

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver by default fetches all rows at once.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel By fetching do you mean that it transfers the whole result set into the mail memory?

Comment: Yes, it is one of my annoyances with the MySQL driver. See specifically http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html under `ResultSet`: _"By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the link. This is one of the biggest design flaws that I have came across in MySQL driver.