# How to get number of rows returned by Resultset while using HSQLDB?

Tags: java, hsqldb, resultset, rowcount

I am getting exception feature not supported while getting the total no of rows using ResultSet.last() function.
I tried using the hsqldb specific connection and ResultSet class but no success.

Can some one guide any way to get the no of rows from result set except looping through all the rows.

the code snippet used for getting no of rows is given below:

```
rs.last();
int total = rs.getRow();
System.out.println("total no of rows in stu are "+total);
rs.beforeFirst()
```

Comment: Why not just do `select count(*) from your_condition` and refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469812/getting-the-count-of-results-returned-by-a-mysql-query-with-jdbc-in-the-most-per/19470146#19470146

Comment: you will have to execute a separate query that returns only the count and use the value , else you will have to run a loop to get the count which isnt appropriat

Comment: Please share your exception

Comment: The exception thrown is :
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: feature not supported

Comment: @Jagdeep Please mention on which line this exception is coming,i think it is on rs.last()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having look at `HSQLDB` api ,it can be done same as for `ORACLE` which is shown below

```
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid";
String USER = "test";
String PASS = "test";
String query = "Select * from mytable";
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if (rs.next()) {
        rs.last();
        System.out.println("total rows is : " + rs.getRow());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Data");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The key in the answer is specifying ResultSet.TYPE-SCROLL_INSENSITIVE. The default does not allow use of rs.last().

Comment: @fredt yes that's right.he has to mention these flags for manipulating the resultset in both direction

Comment: @fredt: Thanks for your help, setting the flag helped to get the count ...:)