# Counting the rows in a table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to count the number of rows in a table (using PHP and Mysql) all of the count() functions I can find only return columns, or array features, is there a function to return the number of rows? Many thanks!

Comment: You mean this  ? http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: Have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: why did you decide that [count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) doesn't return number of rows?

Comment: also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows). It should explain why better and smarter use mysql count().

Answer (score 0):

you can count the number of rows returned by a query.  note that this function is deprecated... it has options on the docs page here.

https://www.php.net/function.mysql-num-rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysqli_num_rows() :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","name","pass","database");

$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

$rowcount now stores the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

would return the number of rows selected by the query, make sure you are not using `count()` in the query itself.

Answer (score -1):

Depending if you are using mysql,  mysqli or PDO query.

if mysql_query rkstar told you how to do it :

if mysqli_query : http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

if PDO : do another query !
$rowCount = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();