# count tuples in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have a mysql table named X and I wanna count number of occurrences of a tuple. For example we have table X as:

```
A B
1 2
1 3 
1 2
```

And I wanna run a query and get results like this:

```
A B Count
1 2 2
1 3 1
```

Is there anyway to do so in mysql?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Aggregate Function - COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in your query.

Use this (assuming your table's name is table1) :

```
select a, b, COUNT(*) as [Count] FROM table1 group by a, b
```